# Z-Index problems with IE6 and html <select> element

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a `<div>` that opens up on a jquery hover event (display goes from `hidden` to `block`).

Sometime it's opens up over some form elements. And of course it works fine in all browsers except IE6.  `<select>` boxes bleed through as if there z-index is higher than the `<div>` tag.  I've tried setting the `<div>` tag with a higher z-index, but it still gets ignored by IE6.

I'm hoping to implement any fix -- jquery or css, I really don't care at this point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no simple workaround for this (see this [MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx)). I know only clever but really really complicated workarounds such as [this one](http://20.targetprocess.com/2006/07/ie6-select-and-z-index-problem.html). Yuck!

Answer (score 0):

z-index is buggy in all versions of IE but IE6 in particular lets "select" always be on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just ditch a browser if customers still use it. IF I am going to put a div on top of an input field (particularily drop down boxes) then I set the .style.visibility to false on the underlying boxes before I put the div on top. It is crude, but it works.