# How to display one DIV over another DIV in IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am writting some html code which have following structure

```
<div style="position:relative">
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <div id="Upper_Element" style="position:absolute;z-index:10"></div> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <div id="Lower_Element" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1"></div> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

here Upper_Element is a YUI autocomplete text box (where suggestion are displayed when user enters anything like google) and Lower_Element is normal drop down box(`<select>`).
In IE6 , When autocomplete suggestion are displayed Lower_Element is displayed over the suggestions list .
In other browser like IE8 its working fine.
I tried position and z-index attributes but no luck.

Please let me know what else can be tried.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your code got lost ;) (there it is again...)

Comment: Definitely need to see your HTML and CSS since the [stacking context](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Lower_Element is a *normal* drop down box"? Is it a `<select>` element or a `<div>` as in your example? If it is a `<select>` then you are seeing a [very old bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx) that affects IE6 and has been asked/solved many times before, for example [Z-Index problems with IE6 and html <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850967/z-index-problems-with-ie6-and-html-select-element) and [iframe shimming or ie6 (and below) select z-index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug)

Comment: You can hide the `<select>` with JavaScript using one of the solutions from the questions linked in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks @andyb :)  Is there any other solution ? As I dont want to hide it.

Comment: If you use jQuery then the [bgiframe](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe) plugin should solve your problem.

Comment: Without doing what bgiframe does yourself, you have to hide it in IE6. As I said in my answer, it is a problem that will never be fixed in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` and `z-index` attribute to position one element above another

Related links:

- http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/position/
- http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/z-index/

Code

```
<div style="position:absolute"> ... </div>
```

Positioning:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px"> ... </div>
```

**UPD**

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <form>
    <div id="upper_element" style="position:absolute; z-index:2">I am top level div!</div>
    <div id="lower_element" style="position:absolute; z-index:1">I am on the bottom of life</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLx6X/

Comment: I don't use neither htmldog nor w3c :), I use russian resources, so I've picked up first what I've googled :)