# Using BGIFRAME in IE6 with YUI Autocomplete

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, yui, bgiframe

I am writing a simple HTML code which uses YUI autocomplete (to display suggestion as you type like Google). But a `<select>` block is getting displayed over the suggestions list in IE6 only.

It is working fine in other browsers.

I used [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) to avoid it because of [z-index bug in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850967/z-index-problems-with-ie6-and-html-select-element) but had no luck.

My simple code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        $('#myContainer').bgiframe();
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #myAutoComplete {
        width:25em; /* set width here or else widget will expand to fit its container */
        padding-bottom:2em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Autocomplete using YUI !</h1>
    <label for="myInput">Search names in our database:</label>
    <div id="myAutoComplete" class="yui-skin-sam">
        <input id="myInput" type="text">
        <div id="myContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>   
        <form action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <select>
                <option value="val1">val1</option>
                <option value="val2">val2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here select is displayed over myContainer (myContainer displays populated suggestions).
I know I am making some blunder.
Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and YUI live in separate namespaces so there shouldn't theoretically be a problem. Are you sure there are no JavaScript errors? Are all the libraries loaded correctly?

Could use [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) instead?

**Edit:** You can configure the [YUI autocomplete to use an iFrame](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/#iframe)! It kind of works in that it does hide the `<select>` but not instantly. This is probably the best solution since it does not needs jQuery or [bgiframe](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/downloads).

**Edit 2:** I was not happy with the speed at which the `<iframe>` was created by YUI so came up with this hack! Here is a complete solution that seems to work in IE6 for me. THe problem is that YUI is in control of the `#myContainer` which seems to break the `bgiframe` that jQuery sets up. So I opted to simply manipulate the height of `#myContainer` with the YUI method hooks. You may need to change this value to fit your layout, but I'm hoping it will work for you.

Sorry the CSS alteration is jQuery. I have never used YUI before and haven't got any idea how to change CSS properties in YUI :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myAutoComplete {
            width:15em; /* set width here or else widget will expand to fit its container */
            padding-bottom:2em;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/autocomplete/assets/skins/sam/autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="yui-skin-sam">
    <div id="myAutoComplete">
        <label for="myInput">Enter a state:</label><br/>
        <input id="myInput" type="text"/>
        <div id="myContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <p>
                <select>
                    <option value="val1">val1</option>
                    <option value="val2">val2</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#myContainer').bgiframe();
        });

        YAHOO.example.Data = {
            arrayStates: [
                'Alabama',
                'Alaska',
                'Arizona',
                'Arkansas',
                'New Hampshire',
                'New Jersey',
                'New Mexico',
                'New York',
                'Wyoming'
            ]
        }

        YAHOO.example.BasicLocal = function() {
            var oDS = new YAHOO.util.LocalDataSource(YAHOO.example.Data.arrayStates);
            var restoreHeight = function(sType, aArgs) {
                $('#myContainer').css({height:'auto'});
            };

            // Instantiate the AutoComplete
            var oAC = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete("myInput", "myContainer", oDS);
            oAC.prehighlightClassName = "yui-ac-prehighlight";
         //   oAC.useIFrame = true; // works but changes the container into an iFrame a bit too late for my liking
            oAC.doBeforeExpandContainer = function () {
                $('#myContainer').css({height:'50px'}); // might need to play around with this value
                return true;
            }
            // restore height
            oAC.containerCollapseEvent.subscribe(restoreHeight);
            oAC.useShadow = true;

            return {
                oDS: oDS,
                oAC: oAC
            };
        }();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant use jquery right now :(  I checked and don't think there are any script error / conflict.

Comment: Um, well you are using jQuery for the "bgiframe" that's why I asked :-) I have updated my answer with something that works although it might not be the nicest UX.

Comment: Heh, looks like I stitched myself up on this one since it was me who recommended bgiframe in the first place when I answered your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621220/how-to-display-one-div-over-another-div-in-ie6)!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is hide the `<select>` (use `visibility:hidden` as not to mess up the layout) at the beginning of the process and show it at the end.

BTW: The likelihood of finding another StackOverflow user using YUI + jQuery + bgiframe + ie6 is quite low. Most users like to help with debugging code, not plug-ins.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus.  I don't want to hide it thats why I am using bgiframe.  I know probabity is low but still I am optimistic as its pissing me off and deadlines are really close.