# IE issue Coolest DHTML Calendar

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [this  open source calendar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptDemo/Calendarwithdifferenttheme.htm) and have the listbox below the date picker button.

When I click the date picker button, the listbox will suddenly hide in IE6, IE7 and IE8. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The link you posted does not work. In any case, if it's broken as you describe, I suspect that this calendar may not be, in fact, the coolest calendar.

Comment: You should probably show the code (JS & HTML) you are using and also make a small demo on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it supposed to be hidden? From the site…

> this select should hide when the calendar is above it

This is to work around the limitation in IE with z-index, see [Z-Index problems with IE6 and html <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850967/z-index-problems-with-ie6-and-html-select-element) and probably many other questions.

The calendar you are using is out of date and you might find you get incompatibilities with newer browsers. I would recommend the [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) for a more up-to-date (and *cooler*) calendar. Although that does mean you would need to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and a [jQueryUI theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) which might not suit your needs.

**Edit:** The code is blindly hiding `<select>` elements for all versions of IE, even though the bug was [fixed in IE7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx) - a year after that calendar library was last updated :-)